# Can't simulate initial login using sudo

Tags: permissions, sudo, users

```
$ sudo -iu cyrus
sudo: unable to change directory to /srv/cyrus: Permission denied
sudo: unable to execute /bin/zsh: Permission denied
```

I don't understand why I would get permission denied for `/bin/zsh` at all:

```
$ stat /bin/zsh
  File: `/bin/zsh' -> `/etc/alternatives/zsh'
  Size: 21          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: ceh/206d    Inode: 49686869    Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2014-05-02 22:19:33.464671249 +0800
Modify: 2014-05-02 22:12:21.447725196 +0800
Change: 2014-05-02 22:12:21.452724872 +0800
 Birth: -
```

and `/srv/cyrus`:

```
$ stat /srv/cyrus/
  File: `/srv/cyrus/'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: ceh/206d    Inode: 50467467    Links: 3
Access: (0750/drwxr-x---)  Uid: ( 1002/  cyrus)   Gid: ( 1002/  cyrus)
Access: 2014-05-02 22:05:57.702641011 +0800
Modify: 2014-05-02 22:05:58.135612918 +0800
Change: 2014-05-02 22:11:39.313461373 +0800
 Birth: -
```

How do I debug this type of problem?

Comment: FWIW All your stat on `/bin/zsh` shows is that it's a symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/zsh` (which is itself probably a symbolic link to the actual executable). You should probably dereference them and show the permissions on the final executable.

Comment: You should also make sure that the `cyrus` user has the executable bit on both `/` and `/srv` since it needs to be able to look up where `/srv/cyrus` is on the filesystem

Answer (score 0):

*How do I debug this type of problem?*

Try without the environment

```
sudo -s -u cyrus
```

You can also trace the system calls.
On Linux :

```
strace sudo -iu cyrus
```

Note that some Linux distribution requires your account to be in a specific group.